# Resource dependency issues in nested cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, aws-cloudformation

I am receiving an error when I try to update my root stack with a new nested stack.

Error:  "Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ProjectsusgetFinancialsLF] in the Resources block of the template".

Here is how I am passing my values to from my main stack to the nested stack:

```
    "Resources": {
    "FinancialStack": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
        "Properties": {
            "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example/child-cft.json",
            "TimeoutInMinutes": "10",
            "Parameters": {
                "DBuser": {
                    "Ref": "DBuser"
                },
                "testDB": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "testDB",
                        "Endpoint.Address"
                    ]
                },
                "DBname": {
                    "Ref": "DBname"
                },
                "DBpass": {
                    "Ref": "DBpass"
                },
                "EnvType": {
                    "Ref": "EnvType"
                },
                "LambdaExecution": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaExecutionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
                    "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi"
                },
                "AuthorizerFuncApiGateway": {
                    "Ref": "AuthorizerFuncApiGatewayAuthorizer"
                },
                "ApiGatewayResourcePortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVar" : {
                    "Ref": "ApiGatewayResourcePortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVar"
                }
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "testDB",
            "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "AuthorizerFuncApiGatewayAuthorizer",
            "ApiGatewayResourcePortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVar"
        ]
    }
```

This is my child stack and the function where the error is getting thrown:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS CloudFormation to generate test one shot deployment",
"Parameters": {
    "DBuser": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "testDB": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "DBname": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "DBpass": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "EnvType": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "LambdaExecution": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "AuthorizerFuncApiGateway": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "ApiGatewayResourcePortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVar": {
        "Type": "String"
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "ProjectsusgetProjectFinancialsLF": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Code": {
                "S3Bucket": "dev",
                "S3Key": "test-lamda.zip",
                "S3ObjectVersion": "9eNYbcI5EOuuut9igX2xpgbGCtKD1D4K"
            },
            "Environment": {
                "Variables": {
                    "MYSQLDB_USER": {
                        "Ref": "DBuser"
                    },
                    "MYSQLDB_HOST": {
                        "Ref": "testDB"
                    },
                    "MYSQLDB_DATABASE": {
                        "Ref": "DBname"
                    },
                    "MYSQLDB_PASSWORD": {
                        "Ref": "DBpass"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Description": "A get project financials function",
            "FunctionName": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "-",
                    [
                        {
                            "Ref": "EnvType"
                        },
                        "getProjectFinancials"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "Handler": "src/controllers/projects.getProjectFinancials",
            "Role": {
                "Ref": "LambdaExecution"
            },
            "Runtime": "nodejs6.10"
        }
    },
```

I am not sure why [ProjectsusgetFinancialsLF] is having unresolved dependencies. I feel like I have provided everything required by the function. I can't figure out what is the issue. Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

Edit: Included the testDB resource in the root stack

```
"       "testDB": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
            "DBName": {
                "Ref": "DBname"
            },
            "DBSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "DBSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "AllocatedStorage": "5",
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "testinst",
            "Engine": "MySQL",
            "EngineVersion": "5.7",
            "MasterUsername": {
                "Ref": "DBuser"
            },
            "MasterUserPassword": {
                "Ref": "DBpass"
            },
            "DBParameterGroupName": {
                "Ref": "RDSDBParameterGroup"
            }
        }
    },"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because in your root stack when you reference epmoliteDB you are not stating that it is an output from another nested stack. For example it should look like.

```
                    "LambdaExecution": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "epmoliteDB", "Outputs.Address" ] 
                }
```

Im also doing this under the assumption in the epmoliteDB you are outputting the correct information. In this case a value called Address

You can find some good examples here 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudformation.html

Also on a side note in your parameters section, when stating your DBpass as a String you also want to add the NoEcho property and set it to true. This will make your password not viewable as plaintext when typing in and updating the stack. For more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html and go to NoEcho

Comment: ePMOliteDB is a resource in my root stack and not a nested stack. As far as I know Output is generated at the end of the stack (please correct me if I am wrong) hence I thought it wasn't possible to pass it to my nested stack in the way you have mentioned.

In my other resources in the root stack I used the same function and it was working.   ` "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "epmoliteDB",
                        "Endpoint.Address"
                    ]`

In the examples they pass values from one nested stack to another which don't apply in my case :(

Comment: Your right about the outputs and it does seem like it'd be passing correctly. I have spotted you said the error was in ProjectsusgetFinancialsLF but in the child stack that resource that you included is called ProjectsusgetProjectFinancialsLF

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the help! I just found the error myself as well !